# when i set a kotlin variable as private, i get an error saying " modifier private are not applicable to local variables

Tags: java, kotlin

```
class Bank_ {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        private val bank_name:String                 
        private val bank_country:String
        private val ank_address:String
        private val bank_code:Int
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because it's true. You cannot declare variables as `private` inside methods.

You can, however, do it at a class level like this:

```
class Bank { 
    private val name: String = ...                 
    private val country: String = ...
    private val address: String = ...
    private val code: Int = ...
}
```

or you should rather do it using data class:

```
data class Bank(
    val name: String, 
    val country: String,
    val address: String,
    val code: Int
)
```

...or at a method level like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val name: String                 
    val country: String
    val address: String
    val code: Int
}
```